# Assigning space to variables in Unix

Tags: shell, unix, echo

Suppose if I want to print 3 variables where the variables are

```
var1="123"
var2="   "
var3="456"
echo $var1$var2$var3
```

The result I got executing the command is `123 456`; I am wanting 3 spaces rather than a single space.

Kindly suggest some technique to print it.

Answer (score 4):

Use double quotes:

```
echo "$var1$var2$var3"
```

Many problems are resolved by using double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
echo $var1"$var2"$var3
```

Results:

```
bcsmc2rtese001 [~]$ var1="123"  
bcsmc2rtese001 [~]$ var2="   "  
bcsmc2rtese001 [~]$ var3="456"  
bcsmc2rtese001 [~]$ echo $var1$var2$var3  
123 456  
bcsmc2rtese001 [~]$ echo "$var1$var2$var3"  
123   456  
bcsmc2rtese001 [~]$ echo $var1"$var2"$var3  
123   456
```

Comment: In general, the double-quotes-around-everything is safer; you usually don't know which of the variables contains significant (multiple) spaces.